# Valid XML Character

Tags: xml

Can you use the plus(+)character in an XML? 
The system creates XML messages with + characters, but I can't remember have seen this in any other XML messages. 
Can anyone tell me if this is valid to send?

```
<body>
  <FHSResponse>
    <workOrderResponse+orderType="DMF"+eventRegistrationByFirstName="Server"+eventRegistrationByLastName="Response"+eventRegistrationDate=""+telephone="99999999"+mobile="99999999"+sendingSent="20190204151304">
      <economicFeedback+status="ØR"+contractorsReference="100000000000214">
        <economicLine+lineNumber="001"+productCode="1010233"+remarks="">
          <economicLineExpense+expenseDescription=""+expenseSum="101.03"+/>
          <attachment+URL=""+/>
        </economicLine>
      </economicFeedback>
    </workOrderResponse>
  </FHSResponse>
</body>
```

Just want to ensure myself that this actually will work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not well-formed XML. The separator between XML attributes must be whitespace (one or more of space, tab, newline, and carriage return).